# What situation does it make sense to mod a toaster oven instead of just buying a reflow oven?

Tags: surface-mount, reflow, buying

I have seen kits like this online

http://whizoo.com/reflowoven

to modify a toaster oven to use as a reflow oven, but they seem like a significant amount more work and lower quality than just buying a reflow oven like

https://www.joyfay.com/catalog/product/view/id/51365/

Both seem to cost ~$200, but one involves a lot more work and risk. Why do people mod their own instead of buying them, just bragging rights or is there some aspect of customization or something I am missing?

Comment: Some people love to spend their time and money for weird stuff. They call it "hobby".

Comment: The fact that this T-962 costs $200 could be some kind of anomaly: maybe someone went out of business and dumped their inventory, maybe it's a reject.  $55 for shipping (from China to US).

Comment: This isn't at outlier, there seem to be several retailers selling them for about this price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason for modifying anything is that you already own it. It is just taking up space with no purpose. Your wife will kill you for modifying the one she is using. You found it a Garage Sale for little or nothing. If the 2 items are of comparable cost, their really would be no advantage to modifying something when you have to buy it new. I do this type of thing all of the time. One of the problems is that you hold onto everything that you ever had for repurposing in the future.

Comment: +1 for enumerating the problem... (looking around the room)

Answer (score 3):

First off -- a toaster oven can be used for reflow *unmodified* with some care and attention -- this allows you to pull yourself by your own bootstraps, if you will, with regards to SMT soldering.

Second -- toaster ovens are much more *readily available* than a true reflow oven.  Not everyone has the luxury of easy/cheap shipping of oven-sized objects to their doorstep, or the ability to shop online even; sometimes a local purchase is the only option, or vastly cheaper than an online purchase due to shipping costs.